# Boiling point of Coca-Cola

Tags: everyday-chemistry, boiling-point

Inspired in part by the question [boiling point of vodka](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/boiling-point-of-vodka) - given that the exact ingredients of Coca-Cola are kept secret, based on what is known, what would a viable prediction of the boiling point of Coca-Cola be?

Would it be significantly different from related products (e.g. Diet Coke, Coke Zero, etc)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your best guess for the boiling point of any version of Coke would be 100 C, the boiling point of water.

Diet Coke is mostly water (the flavourings are a very small amount relative to the amount of water). The largest ingredient will be the sweetener but there will be only a fraction of a gram of that. It is unlikely you will notice any deviation from the properties of water.

Standard Coke has quite a lot of sugar in it. A standard can (~300ml) contains about 40g of sugar. To put it another way, the contents are more than 10% sugar by weight and the solution is about 1/3 mol/L of sucrose (other sugars will be slightly different). A [standard calculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boiling-point_elevation) using the ebullioscopic constant for water suggests the elevation of the boiling point will be barely 0.2 C, so small you'd struggle to measure it without good instruments and a good experimental setup.

Comment: +1 Great answer, so essentially, Coca Cola and just about all soft drinks could be considered as sweetened water,in this respect.

Comment: @Amaterasu Well, that is indeed what they are.

Comment: Atmosferic preasure will produce a greater difference.

Comment: Oh pressure produces diffrence so It depends upon pressure, when the bottle is totally closed it has more pressure etc..

Answer (score 2):

Here's an excellent resource that says the difference between 10% sucrose (aka coke) and water is less than a degree Celsius:
http://kitchenscience.sci-toys.com/boiling_freezing_pressure

Why don't you just measure it? All you need is a bottle of coke, a thermometer and a kitchen. There will be some foam when the CO<sub>2</sub> comes out, so heat slowly or be prepared for a sticky mess.

Comment: I have a bottle of coke and a few kitchen thermometers. Be right back!

Comment: Please do post your results if you get any!